# Multiple Select Listbox is not populating after Remove or add item from list in Select2.js version 3.5.4 And Jquery 1.9

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

> I have Select2 multiselect field in my form where I need to remove
>   and
>           Add item. After remove or add item from multiselect list, its not populating
>           in that click. I have to click again to get back listbox[This is issue.Should populate listbox in remove click as well].
>
> **I know This is working after Select2 Versioin 4.0.**
>   **But In my application I have version 3.5.4.**
>       So what should I have to include in Js and css file to  populate Listbox   after remove item.
>   I attached my fiddle here  with Version 3.5.4

jQuery(function($)
{

```
$('.select2-original').select2({
    placeholder: "Choose elements",
  width: "100%"
})
```

});

http://jsfiddle.net/nparikh/ap4hkbym/37/